# Get and show data from json file in ExtJs

Tags: json, extjs

I am a beginner in ExtJs and I am trying to get and show data from a json file.

The code I used for this:

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
Ext.define('User', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: ['id', 'name', 'email']
    });

    var store = new Ext.data.Store({
    model: 'User',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url : 'example.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json'
        }
    },
    listeners: {
        load: function() {
            records = store.getRange()
            test = records[0].get('id')
            alert(test)
        }
    },
    autoLoad:true
});
});
```

Here is the json file:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Ed Spencer",
        "email": "ed@sencha.com"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Abe Elias",
        "email": "abe@sencha.com"
    }
]
```

The problem is that it doesn't show any data in alert. Please help me to sort it out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have updated the code. it shows only one value, but I want to show all data in the form of array.

Answer (score 0):

You are alerting the Store itself. That is an object that manages the data and not the data itself.

Try:

```
console.log(store.getRange())
```

[`getRange`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-getRange) will get all records in the store in an Array.
I prefer `console.log` over `alert` because you can inspect the data better.

### Edit

Hey, I see you getting closer to your solution with the answers provided.
You must know that `alert` breaks the code chain. So it stop executing code unless you discard the alert.

To answer you second question you can do this to display the result you want in a `string`.

```
var records = store.getRange();
alert( JSON.stringify(records) );
```

Comment: where can I use this Console and how it can show data?

Comment: in the developer console of your browser, press F12 to see it.

Comment: This shows blank array in console and I want this at the web page not in the console.

Comment: @Ravneet updated my answer. I hope this fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using following config in your store
autoLoad: true

sample code

```
Ext.define("Demo.store.Users",{
extend: "Ext.data.Store",
model: "Demo.model.User",
proxy: {

        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'users-browse-remote.php',
        reader: {
             type    : 'json',
             root: 'Users'
         },


 },
autoLoad: true
```

});